# How to change iOS "UITableView negative space" color?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm defining "UITableView negative space" as the space from the bottom of the last cell to the bottom of the table. I want to change the color of that space only, and not the tableView's backgroundColor property.

It's true that I could set the tableView background color to force that space to be a particular color, however I also want the tableView's background color to be clear.

The reason being that setting the tableView background to clear will allow the user to see behind the tableView when a scroll bounce occurs or when doing a pull-to-refresh.

It might be possible with a footer but I'm not sure how to properly size the footer in a dynamic way with various headers and different sized cells.

---

Another way to ask the question: How can I determine the size of the negative space so I can create a footer view of that size only with whatever color?

Comment: Did you try subtracting the height of the table's content view from the height of the table view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could calculate the area from the end of the `UITableView`'s `contentSize` and its `bounds` and if its contentSize is smaller than the bounds add a view above the tableView

I did a quick test to see if it'd work that goes more or less

All the magic happens in `addNegativeSpaceView`.

```
@interface TableViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *negativeSpaceView;
@end

@implementation TableViewController

#pragma mark - View Life Cycle
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Remove all the extra lines below last item
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self addNegativeSpaceView];
}

#pragma mark - Implementation
- (void)addNegativeSpaceView {
    if (self.tableView.contentSize.height < self.tableView.bounds.size.height) {
        CGSize size = CGSizeMake(self.tableView.bounds.size.width, self.tableView.bounds.size.height - self.tableView.contentSize.height);
        CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(0, self.tableView.contentSize.height);
        self.negativeSpaceView.frame = (CGRect){origin, size};
        [self.view insertSubview:self.negativeSpaceView aboveSubview:self.tableView];
    } else {
        [self.negativeSpaceView removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
#pragma mark - Getter
- (UIView *)negativeSpaceView {
    if (!_negativeSpaceView) {
        _negativeSpaceView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 0)];
        _negativeSpaceView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    }
    return _negativeSpaceView;
}
#pragma mark - Table view data source
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 6;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor randomColor];
    return cell;
}
```

That results in [image: kind of like this]

Comment: This is an excellent answer, @mittens!  No modifications necessary! Many thanks.